# How to Hide and show a set of imageson a Single click in HTml5?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am working on a HTML5 windows app in wwhich a screen has a 3 images on up,leftand right side as shown in the image below marked with red.

[image]

All I want to hide that three images on a single click by sliding out the images when the button is clicked. Please provide me code on how to do it using HTMl5/javascript

The Code goes here for the program

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>TamilKarpom</title>

<!-- WinJS references -->
<link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>

<script>
    function diffImage(img) {
        if (img.src.match("images/on_btn.png")) {
            console.log('Low');
            img.src = "images/off_btn.png";
        }
        else {
            console.log('up');
            img.src = "images/on_btn.png";
        }
    }


</script>

<!-- TamilKarpom references -->
<link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/default.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="images/Title.png" id="full-screen-background-image"/>
<img src="images/yellow.png" id="image4"  style="position:absolute; height: 734px; left: 1195px; top: 41px; width: 229px;"/>
<img src="images/glow.png" style="position:absolute" id="full-screen" />
<a href="uyireluthukkal.html">
<img src="images/blue.png" id="image3" style="position:absolute; left: 253px; top: -100px; width: 880px; height: 276px;"/>
</a>
<img src="images/red.png" id="image2" style="position:absolute; width: 220px; left: -48px; top: 24px; height: 734px;"/>
<img src="images/title_01.png"style="position:absolute; left: 330px; top: 58.5px; width: 700px; height: 630px;" />
<img  style="position:absolute; left: 593.5px; top: 636.33px; width: 171px; height: 122.5px;" src="images/off_btn.png"  id="image1"   onclick="diffImage(this); "/>
 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Supply some existing code using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something and it will be easier to help you.

Comment: agree with Alex. You'll get 'practical help' if you setup a JSFiddle

Comment: Or atleast show us your mark-up.

Comment: I have edited the question with the code I used now please help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use a combination of Javascript and CSS. For a good answer, you should have posted some source code, but I'll try:

First, prepare your code to be found by the script. Set the id of the switch to, for example, "switchToHideImages":

```
<img id="switchToHideImages" src=" .....
```

Add a class to the images you want to show/hide, for example "myImages"

```
<img class="myImages" src=" .....
```

Then create a css class called, for example, myImagesHidden:

```
.myImagesHidden {
    display: none; /* this will hide all elements which have this class */
}
```

Then, using jQuery, add this code to the bottom of your HTML page (best practice, to make javascript not slow down the page load).

If you don't have jQuery on your site yet, add this row:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then this, the function itself:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#switchToHideImages").on("click", function(){
            $(".myImages").toggleClass("myImagesHidden");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Clicking the button will now select the images with the class "myImages", and then add the class "myImagesHidden" to them. This will cause them to disappear. If the class "myImagesHidden" is already present on the element (here, the image) when the switch is clicked, it will be removed - causing the images to reappear.

**Edit:**

Like others have already said, a JSFiddle would make it easier to help you and try the code. But try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>TamilKarpom</title>

        <!-- WinJS references -->
        <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <style>
            .myImagesHidden {
                display: none; /* this will hide all elements which have this class */
            }
        </style>

        <!-- TamilKarpom references -->
        <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <img class="myImages" src="images/Title.png" id="full-screen-background-image"/>
        <img class="myImages" src="images/yellow.png" id="image4"  style="position:absolute; height: 734px; left: 1195px; top: 41px; width: 229px;"/>
        <img src="images/glow.png" style="position:absolute" id="full-screen" />
        <a href="uyireluthukkal.html">
            <img class="myImages" src="images/blue.png" id="image3" style="position:absolute; left: 253px; top: -100px; width: 880px; height: 276px;"/>
        </a>
        <img class="myImages" src="images/red.png" id="image2" style="position:absolute; width: 220px; left: -48px; top: 24px; height: 734px;"/>
        <img src="images/title_01.png"style="position:absolute; left: 330px; top: 58.5px; width: 700px; height: 630px;" />
        <img  style="position:absolute; left: 593.5px; top: 636.33px; width: 171px; height: 122.5px;" src="images/off_btn.png"  id="switchToHideImages"   onclick="diffImage(this); "/>

        <!-- TamilKarpom references -->
        <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
        <!-- WinJS references -->
        <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
        <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function diffImage(img) {
                if (img.src.match("images/on_btn.png")) {
                    console.log('Low');
                    img.src = "images/off_btn.png";
                }
                else {
                    console.log('up');
                    img.src = "images/on_btn.png";
                }
            }

            //Add event listener to the switch, and set it to toggle the images with the class "myImages"
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#switchToHideImages").on("click", function(){
                    $(".myImages").toggleClass("myImagesHidden");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```